string indices must be integers Pinecone Embedding
I upserted my indexes on pinecone. One i used dimensions of 1536 and another index is 768. When i use open ai embeding model ada the 1536 runs perfectly fine but if i use any other sentence transformer which is still 1536 i am getting this error. Now trying to make 768 work but still getting the same error when not using open ai embeding model ada.
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']
PINECONE_API_KEY = os.environ['PINECONE_API_KEY']
PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT = os.environ['PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT']

class MeilenWebsiteRetriever():

def __init__(self, index_name, namespace):
    self.index_name = index_name
    self.namespace = namespace

def init_vectorstore(self):

    pc = Pinecone(api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY, environment=PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT)

    if self.index_name not in pc.list_indexes().names():
        pc.create_index(
            name=self.index_name,
            dimension=768,
            metric="cosine"
        )

    #embedding_function = SentenceTransformer('BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5')
    #embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002",
                                #disallowed_special=())
    
    embedding_function = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')

    print('1')
    vectorstore = LangchainPinecone.from_existing_index(
        index_name=self.index_name,
        embedding=embedding_function,
        namespace=self.namespace
    )
    print('2')
    
    return vectorstore

def init_retriever(self, k, return_source_documents=True):
    print('3')
    vectorstore = self.init_vectorstore()
    print('4')
    retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": k},
                            return_source_documents=True)
    print('5')
    return retriever

class JSON_output_sources(BaseModel):
    doc_ids: list = Field(description="list of doc ids")

class MeilenRAGBot():


def __init__(self):
    
    self.retriever = MeilenWebsiteRetriever(
                      index_name="angelos-testing",
                      namespace="factoids-baseemb").init_retriever(k=2, return_source_documents=True)
    self.llm = ChatOpenAI(
                openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
                model="gpt-4-1106-preview",
                temperature=0,
                max_tokens=512,
                streaming=True,
                model_kwargs={
                    "top_p": 0.95,
                  })
    self.conversational_memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
                                  memory_key='chat_history',
                                  input_key="question",
                                  k=3,
                                  return_messages=True)
    self.prompt_template = self.init_prompt_template()
    self.bot = self.init_bot()

def init_prompt_template(self):

    template = """
        Only consider the following pieces of context and chat history to answer the questions. 

        Chat history: {chat_history}
        Context: {context}

        You can only make conversations based on the provided context. 
        If a response cannot be formed strictly using the context, politely say you don’t have knowledge about that topic. 
        If you don’t know the answer to a question, say you don’t know. 
        Ensure that your answers remain exclusively focused on Meilen and maintain language consistency with the incoming questions. 
        Prioritize providing detailed yet concise responses, and approach each question methodically. 
        Remember to take a deep breath and work through each step deliberately.

        Question: {question}
        Answer: """

    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "chat_history", "question"],
                        template=template)

    return prompt_template
    
def init_bot(self):
    print('10')
    bot = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=self.llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=self.retriever,
        chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": self.prompt_template,
                           "memory": self.conversational_memory
                          },
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=False)
        
    return bot
  
def isolate_sources(self, source_docs, answer):
    
    template = """You will be presented with a list of retrieved source documents and an LLM generated answer. Your task is to determine which source documents contributed to the answer.
        
        Approach this task step by step, take your time and do not skip any steps.

        1. Read the generated LLM answer.
        2. Read the source documents.
        3. Determine which source documents in the list of source documents contributed to the answer.
        4. Output a response as JSON with keys as follows:
            - "doc_ids": allowable values are a list of integers (eg. [0, 1, 3])

        Input source documents: {source_docs}

        LLM generated answer: {answer}
    """

    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["source_docs", "answer"], template=template)

    parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=JSON_output_sources)

    prompt = prompt_template.format(source_docs=source_docs, answer=answer)
    res = self.llm([SystemMessage(content=prompt)])

    try:
        doc_ids = parser.parse(res.content).doc_ids
        relevant_sources = [source_docs[i] for i in doc_ids]
        relevant_sources = [{"page_content": source.page_content,
                             "metadata": source.metadata,
                             "uuid": str(uuid.uuid4())} for source in relevant_sources]
    except Exception as e:
        relevant_sources = []

    return relevant_sources

def run_query(self, query):
    print('6')
    
    res = self.bot({"query": query})
    print('7')
    # isolate relevant sources
    relevant_sources = self.isolate_sources(res["source_documents"], res["result"])
    print('8')
    return {
        "answer": res["result"],
        "source_documents": relevant_sources
        }
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

bot = MeilenRAGBot()

while True:
  
    query = input('>')
    
    # run query
    res = bot.run_query(query)

    print(res["answer"])
    print(res["source_documents"])

File "C:\Users\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py", line 62, in forward
trans_features = {'input_ids': features['input_ids'], 'attention_mask': features['attention_mask']}
TypeError: string indices must be integers
